# How to represent Compact isometry transformation matrix in Eigen?

Tags: c++, transformation, eigen

I have a bunch of isometry [R | t] transformation matrices, i.e. they are 3D rigid transformations. Currently I store them as [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/) Affine [transformations](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialGeometry.html), represented in the compact form e.g. `Eigen::AffineCompact3d` which does not stores the redundant last row of [0 0 0 1].

I am also aware that there is a `Eigen::Isometry3d` which I guess is typedef of `Transform<double, 3, AffineCompact, Isometry>`.

I am after Isometry since, the inverse tranformation is much cheaper (transpose) than a general affine inverse. I also know that I can pass a hint, when I use inverse() as `affine_mat.inverse(Eigen::Isometry);`

But I would like to get the isometric inverse behavior without every-time manually passing a hint. In other words, I want to know, what is the best way to replicate the behavior of `Eigen::IsometryCompact3d` which is surprisingly absent in the Eigen API?

Answer (score 1):

To represent isometries I am currently using [twists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_theory). This parametrization can be described by a 6 element vector.

To transform back and forth to the standard homogeneous matrix formulation you will need a couple of functions based on log() and exp() (thus converting will be a slow operation).

This soluiton is favourable if you do not have performance constraint on going back and forth between the two formulation (or you do it rarely) or if you want to exploit the properties of the twists (for instance in numerical optimization)

Comment: Yes its good to have a Lie group represenation generally. But in my case I am doing a transformation of lot of vectors, and the matrix representation works best for me. I think Eigen writers somehow missed this thing.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a little old and you probably found a solution by now. But this might interest others who have this question too.

First thing, You wrote:

> I am after Isometry since, the inverse tranformation is much cheaper (transpose) > than a general affine inverse.

Just to clarify: You **can not** just transpose to get the inverse:

```
/*
    |  R   t|
T = |0 0 0 1|

    |      0|
T' =|  R'  0| not an affine transformation!
    |      0|
    |  t   1|

// inverse of Isometric matrix without actual matrix inversion
T^(-1) = | R'    -R'*t|
         |0 0 0   1   |
*/
```

That sad, you could just define your own function:

```
void invertAffineCompact3d(Eigen::AffineCompact3d &m){   
  m.linear() = m.linear().transpose();
  m.translation() = -m.linear()*m.translation();
}
```

And call it like:

```
Eigen::AffineCompact3d T1 = ...
invertAffineCompact3d(T1);
```

Or, if you want one solution for all types:

```
template<size_t m, size_t n, size_t x, size_t y, typename Derived>
Eigen::Block<Derived, m, n>
  getSubmatrix(MatrixBase<Derived>& data)
{
  return Eigen::Block<Derived, m, n>(data.derived(), x, y);
}

template<typename Derived>
void invertAffine3d(Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> &m){
  getSubmatrix<3,3,0,0>(m).transposeInPlace();
  getSubmatrix<3,1,0,3>(m) = -getSubmatrix<3,3,0,0>(m)*getSubmatrix<3,1,0,3>(m);
}
```

And call it like:

```
Eigen::AffineCompact3d T2 = ...
invertAffine3d(T2.matrix());

Eigen::Affine3f T3 = ...
invertAffine3d(T3.matrix());


Eigen::Isometry3d T4 = ...
invertAffine3d(T4.matrix());
```

If you are really fancy you could expand MatrixBase using [EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN](https://tmp.mosra.cz/eigen-docs/TopicCustomizing_Plugins.html)